# Creating a column based on rows conditions

Tags: r, multiple-columns, dplyr

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
user_id  Gap itr    visit_no.(desired column)
      a  0.3   1            1
      a  0.5   1            1
      a  1.5   1            1
      a  0.9   1            2
      a  2.6   1            2
      a 0.34   1            3
      a  0.8   2            1
      a 0.34   2            1
      b  1.6   1            1
      b  0.7   1            2
      b  0.8   1            2
      b  0.7   1            2
      b  4.8   2            1
      b 0.39   2            2
      b 0.38   2            2
      b 0.89   2            2
```

I want to create column (visit_no.). Whenever gap is more than 1 , we need to increase visit_no. value by 1 in next rows and it would remain same till we find another value>1 , we would keep assigning serial number in increasing order.If gap is less than 1 , then value of visit_no would be given in previous rows of visit_no. And visit_no. would always start from 1 for a user and itr ..Visit_No column has be grouped by user_id and itr

This is the dataframe

```
df<-data.frame(user=c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b")
                    , gap=c(0.3,0.5,1.5,0.9,2.6,0.34,0.8,0.34,1.6,0.7,0.8,0.7,4.8,0.39,0.76,0.72),
                     itr=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2))
```

Comment: Can you please revise your desired column? Include all values and make sure they are correct

Comment: The desired output looks not very well formatted...is Gap 0.034 in row 6? whats with all the a and b in your first column? It's not entirely clear to me what you want to do.

Comment: Yes 6th row of Gap is 0.34 .....Data is formatted properly

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

df<-data.frame(user=c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b")
               , gap=c(0.3,0.5,1.5,0.9,2.6,0.34,0.8,0.34,1.6,0.7,0.8,0.7,4.8,0.39,0.76,0.72),
               itr=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2))

df %>%
  group_by(user, itr) %>%
  mutate(visit_no = cumsum(ifelse(lag(gap, default = 2) > 1, 1, 0))) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 16 x 4
#     user   gap   itr visit_no
#   <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1      a  0.30     1        1
# 2      a  0.50     1        1
# 3      a  1.50     1        1
# 4      a  0.90     1        2
# 5      a  2.60     1        2
# 6      a  0.34     1        3
# 7      a  0.80     2        1
# 8      a  0.34     2        1
# 9      b  1.60     1        1
# 10     b  0.70     1        2
# 11     b  0.80     1        2
# 12     b  0.70     1        2
# 13     b  4.80     2        1
# 14     b  0.39     2        2
# 15     b  0.76     2        2
# 16     b  0.72     2        2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much the same as AntoniosK answer, but in `data.table`, without piping operators, and with `data.table`'s `shift`-function.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, visit_no := cumsum(ifelse(shift(gap, n = 1, type = "lag", fill = 0)>1,1,0)) + 1, by = c("user", "itr")]
dt
#    user  gap itr visit_no
# 1:    a 0.30   1        1
# 2:    a 0.50   1        1
# 3:    a 1.50   1        1
# 4:    a 0.90   1        2
# 5:    a 2.60   1        2
# 6:    a 0.34   1        3
# 7:    a 0.80   2        1
# 8:    a 0.34   2        1
# 9:    b 1.60   1        1
#10:    b 0.70   1        2
#11:    b 0.80   1        2
#12:    b 0.70   1        2
#13:    b 4.80   2        1
#14:    b 0.39   2        2
#15:    b 0.76   2        2
#16:    b 0.72   2        2
```